# what is the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asked this question before but in a different way which seems to be misunderstood, so I`m asking again in another way and I hope I can find answers.

First, The title is the main question, I want to know what is the `.NET Framework`?

and what is the difference between each of the following:

`C#` and `C#.NET`

`ASP` and `ASP.NET`

is there a `C++.NET` or `JAVA.NET`??

Last Question:

What is the difference between each version of the `.NET Frameworks (3, 3.5, 4)`?

Comment: Voting to close this as there's a wealth of information.... but what boggles my mind is .NET has celebrated 10 years birthday this year before 2011.... :o so where were you exactly hiding? Mars?

Comment: close , there are many duplicates

Comment: This dude has already had this same question closed once before, so I figured I'd throw him a bone.

Comment: I would have voted to close as well, but couldn't find the duplicates. Also, I notice the ".NET" tag wiki and FAQ don't easily answer these questions.

Comment: @user: yeah, at least he improved his title.

Comment: @sikas: you might try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa496123.aspx

Comment: @tommieb75 I don't think you need to vote for closing this question. I have seen programmers with 3-4 years of experience who create desktop applications using .Net, but they have never heard of Registry. May be sikas rarely reads.

Answer (score 7):

To answer each question in turn:

- "What is the .NET Framework?" This is a big question - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework
- There is no such thing as C#.NET. There is only C#; all C# compilers target the .NET Framework.
- ASP and ASP.NET are two technologies for building web sites. They have similar names, but work differently. (ASP is built on pre-.NET Visual Basic; ASP.NET is newer.)
- There is a C++ compiler that targets the .NET Framework. The language is referred to as C++/CLI.
- At one point there was a Java compiler that targetted the .NET Framework, but this is no longer available.
- The differences between the versions of the .NET Framework are large, and are explained elsewhere on the web (see the Wikipedia link). Later versions of the .NET Framework have more features than earlier ones.

Comment: @Tim Robinson: So, when I develop an application in `C#` (`GUI` not `Console Application`) it is automatically compiled with the `.NET Framework`? When should I use the `ASP` and when should I use the `ASP.NET` (can you give me sample website idea built on each)?

Comment: Correct, all C# applications use the .NET Framework. For web applications, you should not use ASP; it has been obsolete since ASP.NET was introduced in 2002.

Comment: Not all `C#` compilers target the .net framework. `gmcs` for unix targets mono.

Comment: When reading my answer, replace the words "the .NET Framework" with "a framework like .NET"

Comment: @Tim Robinson: How to differentiate between an `ASP` code and an `ASP.NET` code?

Comment: @sikas: what are you asking? If you're forced to work on ASP code, you'll know. It's been obsolete for eight years.

Comment: @sikas ASP files have a .asp extension, whereas by default ASP.NET uses .aspx

Comment: @John Saunders: I`m not forced to work on ASP Code. I`m just asking because I`m willing to start learning ASP

Comment: @sikas: don't spend any time learning ASP. Only ASP.NET.

Comment: @sikas You can find a simple tutorial on ASP at http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp and on ASP.Net at http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp . Though I would recommend don't learn ASP if it is not required.

Answer (score 4):

Start here. This should answer most of your questions

[.NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)

Answer (score 1):

The [.NET framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/netframework) is a virtual machine plus libraries and development tools from Microsoft.

C# is a language that was designed to be compiled to the .NET framework. There is no such thing as C#.NET, although this it is a common error to call C# this.

ASP is short for "Active Server Pages" and is a technology also designed by Microsoft to aid programmers in the creation of web sites with dynamic content. ASP.NET is the rebirth of this technology running on the :NET framework.

There is a language very similar to C++ called [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) that can be compiled to run on .NET.